# Asking GPS / tracking device specific questions on GIS SE?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions related to GPS / tracking devices in this community, or is this only for software related questions? I need protocol information about some devices that have just arrived, but haven't been able to get any documents from our provider.

If not suitable here, could anyone please provide hints on where to ask for information? Devices are from SECAR

Comment: What is the tracker model number ?

Comment: @Shiko I have two device models that I need to do integrate. According to the stickers attached to them, they are: GPSSECAR816.442 CL and ITC802V 0B 08 03 CL

Comment: Did you manage to connect to devices and get the GPSdata ?

Comment: @Shiko unfortunately not yet, strange connector and no docs :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIS SE is not only for software related questions, although those make up the bulk of what gets posted.

I have not been able to find a Stack Exchange site where your question would be amongst its "core business".

I have also not been able to find anything in our Help to indicate whether your question would be clearly on-topic or off-topic here.

Consequently, I suggest that you [ask it on our Main site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and see how it is received by our community.

We seem to have had about 10 [questions in the vicinity of yours](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgps%5D%20protocol%20is%3Aquestion) and about half of them have attracted answers.